# what is the equivalent of ruby YAML.load(object) and YAML.dump(serialized_str) in java

Tags: java, android, ruby, serialization, deserialization

In ruby, i can serialize and deserialize like this:

```
# file.rb
class C

end

s = YAML.dump(C.new)
# other_file_and_other_time.rb
r = YAML.load(s)
puts "r.inspect:#{r.inspect} ---- #{::File.basename __FILE__}:#{__LINE__}"
# r.inspect:#<C:0x007f4ff27e6c08> ---- timer.rb:9
```

in java, i can do similar thing like this:

```
package ro.ex;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

class Ex {
    static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
        public MyArrayList(Collection c) {
            super(c);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // file.java
        String s = new Gson().toJson(new Ex());
        // otherFile.java
        Object r = new Gson().fromJson(s, Ex.class);
        System.out.println(r + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    }

}
```

but i expect omit type argument:

```
package ro.ex;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

class Ex {
    static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
        public MyArrayList(Collection c) {
            super(c);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // file.java
        String s = new Gson().toJson(new Ex());
        // otherFile.java
        Object r = new Gson().fromJson(s);
        System.out.println(r + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    }

}
```

**so my question is: how to deserialize without specific type.(pass last code)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a "duck", dynamic typing language, because of it, you can do things like that.
But Java has a static, safe and strong typing discipline, so you can't do something like that.

However since you have tagged your question under "android" tag, the [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) could help you, requires a little bit more of code but it's what you're looking for.

Also check these links:

- [auto-parcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel): "Parcelable generation" library, por of Google AutoValue.
- [android-parcelable-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin)
- [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler): another library, haven't used it, but seems to be more popular.